# How to use SSL with ActiveMQ via localhost

Tags: java, network-programming, message-queue

I am attempting to connect to an activeMQ message broker locally via SSL/TLS, but I am having trouble getting authentication to work correctly.

I have followed the [instructions](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html) from the activeMQ site regarding SSL, and I have followed the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696121/how-to-activemq-in-ssl) of this other user's solution. I have set up activemq.xml as follows:

> ```
>    <transportConnectors>
>        <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61714?trace=true&amp;needClientAuth=true"/>
>    </transportConnectors>
> ```

and:

> ```
>    <sslContext>
>       <sslContext keyStore="file:/home/tom/apache-activemq-5.15.8/conf/broker.ks" 
>             keyStorePassword="password" 
>             trustStore="file:/home/tom/apache-activemq-5.15.8/conf/client.ks" 
>             trustStorePassword="password" />
>    </sslContext>
> ```

I then run the following code as a runnable JAR file in the activeMQ base directory:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String uri = "ssl://0.0.0.0:61714";
        ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(uri);

        System.out.println("about to create the connection");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        System.out.println("about to start the connection");
        connection.start();

    }
```

with the following arguments, ran in the activeMQ base directory:

> java -jar -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=conf/client.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=conf/client.ts "App.jar"

While also running the activemq console. This is the top of the error stack trace from the JAR:

```
about to create the connection 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport (file:/home/tom/apache-activemq-5.15.8/App_lib/activemq-all-5.15.8.jar) to method sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setHost(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.activemq.util.IntrospectionSupport
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: ssl://0.0.0.0:61714. Reason: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

And this is the top of the stack from the activeMQ console:

```
 INFO | Connector ssl started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.8 (localhost, ID:toms-HP-Notebook-PC-37849-1548377226145-0:1) started
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
 INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
 INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
 INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
ERROR | Could not accept connection from tcp://127.0.0.1:38482 : {}
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:214)[:]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:159)[:]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2046)[:]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.processInputRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1207)[:]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1074)[:]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)[:]
```

I am unsure whether I have a fundamental misunderstanding about activeMQ, or I'm missing a small detail somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In your activemq.xml config sslContext element, you've specified the incorrect file in the trustStore attribute.

It should specify **broker.ts** on this attribute instead of client.ks

[image: amqBug]

This attribute is used for the broker specifying its truststore of client public certs it trusts.  It's used for ssl mutual authentication where the broker authenticates the client connections based on the client cert being trusted or not.