# ActiveMQ with ssl certificate authentication (two way)

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

Does anyone have experience with ActiveMQ and C#?.
I want to implement ActiveMQ client, but the problem is that I want use SSL.
I have trustStore and keyStore files and passwords.
Will anybody be able to explain me whether it is possible or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to activemq in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696121/how-to-activemq-in-ssl)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activemq in ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696121/how-to-activemq-in-ssl)